# Android app won't work

Tags: java, android

I decided to program my first Android app. I want a simple app which makes a sound after a random amount of time. This should be repeated 20 times (the minutes should be another amount every time). This should be activated by a button. I've implemented butterknife in my program.

This is my method:

```
@OnClick(R.id.startbutton)
void spielen() {
    for(int i=0; i<20;i++) {
        int rando = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1);  //create a random int from 1-10
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000*rando);                 //delay the for loop by random*1min
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity, this, R.raw.fischkarte);

        cheer.start();                                 //play the sound
    } //start the loop again (20 times)
}            // now you should be able to push the button again and start it all over again
```

The error is with this line of code:

```
MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity, this, R.raw.fischkarte);
```

the program says that it was

> expecting an expression.

I'm really new to Android and I have this line from a youtube video. So any suggestions?

Comment: I guess it should be 'MainActivit.this' instead of "MainActivity, this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**
In your case, you have a mistype with that line.
Instead of:

```
MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity, this, R.raw.fischkarte);
```

Use:

```
MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.fischkarte);
```

MediaPlayer static method `create()` takes two arguments, not three. Also, you can't just send only the activity name.

**Second:**
I think you'll face another problem if you interrupt a Main thread.
Try instead stop a sound after some time and after start it again.